# How to pass offset and per_page variables in join query in codeigniter way

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

How to pass offset and perpage count in the below query

```
        $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from($this->table1);
        $this->db->join($this->table2, 'plot.location_id = locations.location_id');
        $this->db->join($this->table3, 'plot.plot_type = plot_types.plot_id');
        $this->db->join($this->table4, 'plot.user_id = admin.id');


        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

Comment: The question already answered and accepted.But I Cannot understand what problem with your codes, Its seems OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->limit();
```

Lets you limit the number of rows you would like returned by the query

Comment: It is better to read documentation, for example here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html 
I'm a bad storyteller :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i tried with limit.. it works thanks

Below is the code

```
        $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from($this->table1);
        $this->db->join($this->table2, 'plot.location_id = locations.location_id');
        $this->db->join($this->table3, 'plot.plot_type = plot_types.plot_id');
        $this->db->join($this->table4, 'plot.user_id = admin.id');
        $this->db->order_by($this->table1.'.plot_id','DESC');
        $this->db->limit($per_page, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```